# How to make a search box which can pointing cursor over (mouse over) an image of submit button?

Tags: javascript, submit, search-engine, imagebutton, onmouseover

I modified a search engine of Google in my site. To understand it please review it at http://www.heypy.com . It's located at top left of the site. What I want is an onmouseover function after users type a keyword in the search box, and easily mouse over the google logo submit button without have to click on it to start a search. i want the search result to be opened in new tab, not new window

Maybe it's ridiculous question but so hard to find tutorial of that case. Anyone expert here please give me a hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you give an id to your form like and set target to "_new"

```
<form id="formID" method="get" 
action="https://www.google.com/search" target="_new">
```

Then add onmouseover to

```
<input id="example" type="IMAGE" ..
onmouseover="search();">
```

To open in new tab:

```
function search(){
    document.getElementById("formID").submit();
}
```

Comment: onmouseover or onmoushover? hehe

Comment: the onmouseover fuction is worked but i want the search result to open in new tab using google chrome. please fix it.

Comment: what's specific u want?. i tell everything.. i want the search result to be opened in new tab, not new window.

Comment: ok my mistake of not know how to open the search result in new tab. not because the code which given by @Gnhn..sorry..

Comment: You need to enable pop ups in your browser settings, otherwise, it won't open new tab/page and continues to open in the same page.

Comment: i was enabled pop up but still same issue